# SQL Server 2008 SMS vs Visual Studio 2010 Server Explorer results

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, server-explorer

i am having a problem with my SQL query that I wrote in Sql Server 2008 Express SMS and am using inside of Visual Studio 2010.

Basics: There is an input box on a web page. It is used to search for a persons name, address, id, etc. When I use a persons name on the website, or inside of the built in Visual Studio Server Explorer, such as "Kargul" (made up), it won't return any results using my Stored Procedure. **However**, in SQL Server 2008 Express SMS, the same Stored Procedure returns a valid result.

Is there something I am missing? Here is my Procedure:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @vars NVARCHAR(50);
SET @vars = '%' + @searchTerm + '%';

SELECT a.PersonId, Stat.StatusId, a.Honorific, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Street1, a.Street2, a.City, a.State, a.Zip, a.Phone, a.Email FROM Persons AS a
JOIN dbo.PersonStatus as Stat
ON a.StatusId = Stat.StatusId
    WHERE
        a.FirstName LIKE (@vars)
        UNION
        SELECT a.PersonId, Stat.StatusId, a.Honorific, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Street1, a.Street2, a.City, a.State, a.Zip, a.Phone, a.Email FROM Persons AS a
            JOIN dbo.PersonStatus as Stat
            ON a.StatusId = Stat.StatusId
                WHERE
        a.LastName LIKE (@vars)
        UNION
        SELECT a.PersonId, Stat.StatusId, a.Honorific, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Street1, a.Street2, a.City, a.State, a.Zip, a.Phone, a.Email FROM Persons AS a
            JOIN dbo.PersonStatus as Stat
            ON a.StatusId = Stat.StatusId
                WHERE
        a.Street1 LIKE (@vars)
        UNION
        SELECT a.PersonId, Stat.StatusId, a.Honorific, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Street1, a.Street2, a.City, a.State, a.Zip, a.Phone, a.Email FROM Persons AS a
            JOIN dbo.PersonStatus as Stat
            ON a.StatusId = Stat.StatusId
                WHERE
        a.City LIKE (@vars)
        UNION
        SELECT a.PersonId, Stat.StatusId, a.Honorific, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Street1, a.Street2, a.City, a.State, a.Zip, a.Phone, a.Email FROM Persons AS a
            JOIN dbo.PersonStatus as Stat
            ON a.StatusId = Stat.StatusId
                WHERE
        a.PersonId LIKE (@vars)
        UNION
        SELECT a.PersonId, Stat.StatusId, a.Honorific, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Street1, a.Street2, a.City, a.State, a.Zip, a.Phone, a.Email FROM Persons AS a
            JOIN dbo.PersonStatus as Stat
            ON a.StatusId = Stat.StatusId
                WHERE
        a.State LIKE (@vars)
    ORDER BY PersonId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a profiler trace on the server to see what is executing when run through VS2010; Is it possible the search parameter is not getting passed? Or maybe you need a SET NOCOUNT ON in your proc.

Comment: sorry, i have a SET NOCOUNT ON on the proc, i just exluded it from the example. I added it in now. Also, when I right click on the Stored Proc in VS and select EXECUTE, manually passing in the param, I get 0 results in the OUTPUT window.